# How to put JTextField a random text?

Tags: java, project, jtextfield, shuffle

I want to show the shuffle word inside the Textfield.
so far this is my random code:

```
    public MyTextTwist(String w){
        if (w != null){
            word = getRandomWord();
                txtWord.setText(word);}

        GameOver = false;
    }

       private String getRandomWord(){
                ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>(txtWord.getText().length());
                for ( char c : word.toCharArray() ) {
                    chars.add(c);
                }
                Collections.shuffle(chars);
                char[] shuffled = new char[chars.size()];
                for ( int i = 0; i < shuffled.length; i++ ) {
                    shuffled[i] = chars.get(i);

                }String shuffledWord = new String(shuffled);
                return shuffledWord;
        }
```

It Doesn't show.

Comment: Sorry, what's your problem with this code again? I'm having trouble understanding your last sentence "it wont word. I want to use that in my twist button." If you mean "it won't work", then please tell us how and why it won't work. Are you getting error messages? If so, please show them.

Comment: I have a textfield but i can't put a word on my textfield what i want to put is the shuffled letters.

Comment: Do you want to replace the word present in the JTextField with the suffled text? If so, you could simply call `txtWord.setText(shuffledWord);` at the bottom of this method. Either that or have the code that's calling this method use the returned String and place it in the JTextField or wherever else it likes.

Comment: no i want to put a shuffled letters on the text. For an example when i run the program the shuffled word is automatically show in the textfield.

Comment: that's what I've told you how to do.

Comment: i put it on my constructor but it doesn't show.

Comment: You are still not giving us near enough information to be able to understand what your problem is. You need to show more code, preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org) and give more description so we can see for ourselves just what your problem is. We cannot read minds, and we cannot see code of yours that you have not posted.

Comment: Kindly check it again. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Where do you try to put the text back into the text field?

Comment: yes. i want to put the ShuffledWord into my JtextField(txtWord).

Comment: You can't do this in a constructor. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, if you want to put the text back into the JTextField, the code must do this by calling setText(...) on the JTextField, but you can't do this in the constructor since when the constructor has been called, the user hasn't had a chance to enter any text into the JTextField. Instead you must call this method in the response to an event, perhaps in an ActionListener that has been added to a JButton:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestWordScramble extends JPanel {
   private JTextField txtWord = new JTextField(10);
   private JButton scrambleBtn = new JButton("Scramble");

   public TestWordScramble() {
      scrambleBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String word = getRandomWord(txtWord.getText());
            txtWord.setText(word);
         }
      });

      add(txtWord);
      add(scrambleBtn);
   }

   private String getRandomWord(String text) {
      ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
      for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
         chars.add(c);
      }
      Collections.shuffle(chars);
      char[] shuffled = new char[chars.size()];
      for (int i = 0; i < shuffled.length; i++) {
         shuffled[i] = chars.get(i);

      }
      String shuffledWord = new String(shuffled);
      return shuffledWord;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TestWordScramble mainPanel = new TestWordScramble();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestWordScramble");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Very nice Hovercraft Full Of Eels! +1

Comment: thanks! for your nice code. But the other problem is not yet solve. i want the word is automatically shown in the textfield just like the real texttwist game. can i use the same process or logic?

Comment: Automatically how? On program creation? If so, where does the String come from? After the user types it in? Surely you don't want the word to scramble as the user enters it, right? If after the user enters it, what event will trigger the word to scramble? You need to give us all the details, especially why the current suggestions haven't helped you.

Comment: "here inside the WordGenerator.generator(). No. the user only type the guessPad." -- sorry, but this doesn't make sense to me. You're replying as if we fully understand your program including parts not posted here. Please explain exactly what you're trying to do as if we have no clue as to what your program does, as if we can't read your mind.

Comment: This is very helpful. also i want an automatic random words/string to the textfield. whisch will get at String generator().

Comment: @Hilver: I think we need to get a better understanding of your program and your problem. I suggest that you create an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org), a small program that runs and compiles and shows kind of what you're trying to do. An example of an SSCCE is the program I've posted above since you can copy the code and run it unmodified from your computer. Please create one of these, post it, and then message me back and I'll have a look at it. Doing this will allow me and others to much better understand your problem and then be much better able to help you.

Comment: Okay Ill will make one. Thanks a lot Sir. God bless I need to sleep.